# How to customize whether a request follow the 302 by one okhttpclient

Tags: android, okhttp

Currently, we only have one okhttpclient in our app, by some of our request need to intercept the original reponse and some want to follow the redirect.

we can identify the request whether it needs to redirect, but a okhttp client only has a global param to control this, how can we customize for each request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a network Interceptor to remove the server response’s `Location` header. If you need that data you can put it into another header like `Rewritten-Location`. Either way if the location header is absent the response will not be redirected.